# Customizing default android layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

Is there a way to customize the default layouts that android presents for phone calls? That is, can I add a button above the end call button?

Something like image below

[image]

Or would I have to create my own phone interface, intercept the phone call and handle the call myself

Answer (score 0):

Try contacting this guy http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1575395 he should have the answer you are looking for.

Comment: I shot him a message. The more I think about it the more it seems as if you'd need to create a broadcast receiver and present your own custom view